# Passing UIButton state to another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

My `FirstViewController` programically creates X number of UIButtons, where X=number of nodes in my array. From this view controller, the user can toggle a button(s) on/off before segueing to the `SecondViewController`. I need to send the button states to the SVC, but the catch is that the buttons share the same name and are identified only by their `tag`.

```
if (((FirstViewController *)self.presentingViewController).scoreButton.selected == YES)
{

}
```

The above code doesn't seem to work, I think because the tag isn't included. Is there another way to call the UIButton that identifies its tag and reads its `selected` state?

Comment: `[view viewWithTag:12345];`?

Comment: I need to retrieve the value of scoreButton.selected for each instance of scoreButton.

Comment: Are you setting the tags programmatically or in interface builder?

Comment: Programmatically. Everything is programmatically because the number of `scoreButton`s needed changes based on the array node accessed.

Comment: You should probably store the buttons you create in an array you can access later, rather than trying to access them by tag if it isn't set at build-time